# Get URL to my media player from Firestore by using redux

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I try to add my URL from firebase to my mediaplayer by using redux. If I print my URL in a text component in my flatlist, the URL display. But when I try to set the url to my media player it doesn't work. If I just copy the url from firebase it works. So what schould I do if I want my URL adress from Firebase by using redux?

```
    async function playSound() {
    console.log('Loading Sound');
    const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(

        {uri: 'Url copied from firebase storage works fine here.'}

        //But if I try to get URL from my redux I doesn't work.
        {uri: userSongs.downloadURL}
    );
```

When I set the url in my flatlist like this it works fine.

```
        <FlatList
            numColumns={3}
            horizontal={false}
            data={userSongs}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
               <View> 
                   <Text>{item.downloadURL}</Text>
               </View>
                )}
            />
```

this is my action.js in my redux

```
export function fetchUserSongs() {
return ((dispatch) => {
    firebase.firestore()
        .collection("users")
        .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
        .collection("usersSong")
        .orderBy("creation", "asc")
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
            let posts = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
            
                const data = doc.data();
                const id = doc.id;
                return { id, ...data }
            })
            dispatch({ type: USERS_SONGS_STATE_CHANGE, posts })
           console.log(posts);
        })
     
})
```

}

Comment: Please share complete code including the Firebase Storage part.

Comment: I added my action.js, is that enough? Cause I get my URL from my Firestore Collection "usersSong". @Dharmaraj

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can do that? @Dharmaraj